# When comparing food processor models, why do some have additional blades?

Tags: food-processing

What are advantages or disadvantages to a middle blade in the food processor? Might this shape be harder to clean than a single-blade model?

It's also called top blades:

[image: multi-blade food processor models]

Comment: Hey, you need to narrow down this question a bit; you're asking like 5 different things here.  Maybe make it JUST about the middle blade, and not all those other questions?

Comment: Asking what features people look for is opinion based so off topic. If all you want is to make smoothies a stick blender is a better and cheaper option.

Comment: This seems to be a pretty good guide: https://www.techgearlab.com/topics/kitchen/best-food-processor

Comment: Nice guide, thanks Gigili! No GdD, smoothies are not all I want to make. I already have a blender. Additionally, the question was edited to include "what features might be nice to have" as an optional addendum.

Comment: Sorry, voting to close this question due to lack of focus.  If you edit it to be asking just one clear question, I'll reverse that.

Comment: Edited ..... :/

Comment: Adamaero:  just a warning, I can see deleted posts.

Comment: ----------->

Answer (score 1):

The [Robot Coupe](https://www.robot-coupe.com/en-usa) is widely regarded as the standard food processor for professional use.  Neither it, nor the industry-leading Cuisinart or KitchenAid food processors have those middle blades.  As such, it seems unlikely that they are requirements for a quality unit.

Answer (score -4):

> The maximum rating is based without the top blades inserted into the pitcher. This drives the greatest power.

> TIP: When pureeing, use only the bottom blades for best results.

> **Top [middle] blades are needed to power through tough ingredients like ice, solid fruits and vegetables.**

http://content.abt.com/documents/51012/BL830_OwnMan.pdf

---

Bonus idea

For the prices I'm looking at ($100-200), it almost seems worth it to get rid of my current blender, buy a combination attachment blender--with food processor and portable blender containers:

[image]

Related: [blades be sharpened or replaced?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/114448/73063)

Comment: Why is this answer getting downvotes? It directly answers the question, "Top [middle] blades are needed to power through tough ingredients like ice, solid fruits and vegetables."

Comment: Not the downvoter, but having blended ice, fruits, and vegetables, I can tell you categorically that a middle blade is not required. It’s probably not a good idea to take that company’s marketing material’s word for it.

Comment: @Sneftel It's in the manual, not "marketing materials."

Comment: :-) You were curious about whether a particular feature was important; you went googling; you found something from the manufacturer, saying that it is. That is an example of marketing.

Comment: Um, no, I first found it from a customer review. You're still clinging to the manual being "marketing materials." It's not. Additionally, I never claimed nor thought it to be "important."

Comment: Btw, I generally agree. A middle blade is likely for marketing purposes. Although, I doubt I'll write that into my answer. That would be more-so an opinion. And I'm not involved with blender companies to actually know.

Comment: Think of my question as analogously "why do a few submarines have two propellers" (and less as a self-fulfilling prophecy).